# How to force ie to ask for digital certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, digital-certificate

Well... I have a web page that requires a digital certificate.

When i first Load the page I get a dialogue window asking for the certificate. If I select it then everything work great :) However, if I press cancel and then re-enter the page I am not prompted for the certificate... The page is rendered and a "The page requires a client certificate" Error is displayed.

How can "force" the dialogue window to choose the certificate to show up every time I enter the page?

Comment: What version of IE?  I've noticed on IE6 that if you cancel, it keeps this in the SSL state, and you have to clear it on the browser side to get it to ask again.

Comment: I am using ie7 and i am getting the same...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an IE problem, it's a webserver problem.  You have to configure your website, at the server, to require digital certificates.  In IIS this done through the Directory Security tab of the site properties.  You have to check "Require SSL", then you can select the option "Require client certificates."

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself correctly. I have the "Require client certificates." option selected, and the FIRST time i load the page it asks me for the certificate. My problem is if I don't choose one from the store, when I open the page for a SECOND time, I am not prompt for the certificate...

Answer (score 0):

With IE you have to do this: Within the Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom Level… UI, the explanatory text has been changed.

- In IE6 and IE7, it reads:
      Do not prompt for client certificate selection when no certificates or only one certificate exists.
- In IE8, it now reads: Don't prompt for client certificate selection when only one certificate exists.

Disable it !